# jquery mobile - slide stop function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slide

I would run a function when I stop to slide the Jquery Mobile Slide.

I have this slide:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
    <label for="slider2">
       Test
    </label>
             <input type="range" name="slider" id="testslider" value="0" min="-50" max="50" data-highlight="true" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And This Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider2" ).bind( "stop", function(event, ui) {
        alert("Stop");
    });      
});
```

But It don't work!

How I can run a function when I release the mouse (finger)??

Comment: Seems like this would answer the question... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-execute-javascript-code-when-finger-is-lifted-from-a-slider

Comment: Work Only if I release the mouse on the slider. If I release the mouse on another place of the page it's dont' work.

Comment: I believe the HTML id for the slider is wrong in this example.

`<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider2" value="0" min="-50" max="50" data-highlight="true" />`

Answer (score 4):

The right method is the following:

```
$("#slider2").on(
   'slidestop',
   function(event) {
      // Code goes here
   }
);
```